# Battle of Numbers

Tags: java

Hi everyone I'm a newbie in Java and I have a sample problem. I also have my own solution. Is there any other better way to solve this problem?

In far far away kingdom, there were battles of numbers. The king in that kingdom asks you to create a program that will determine the winner / champion of that event. The number of contestant is undetermined. The winner of the match is usually the BIGGEST number. The match is a single elimination. The sequence of the match is First IN vs Last IN, Second In vs Last Second In, etc... If there are no opponents for a particular number, he or she will be considered as default winner.

Sample Output:

Enter the Number of Contestant: 5

Enter Contestant # 1: 50

Enter Contestant # 2: 30

Enter Contestant # 3: 8

Enter Contestant #4: 11

Enter Contestant #5: 20

Simulation:

Round 1: 50 vs 20 Winner is: 50

Round 2: 30 vs 11 Winner is: 30

Round 3: Default Winner is: 8

Next …

Round 4: 50 vs 8 Winner is: 50

Round 5: Default Winner is 30

Next …

Round 6: 50 vs 30 Winner is: 50

Champion: 50

Total Bracket Matches: 3

Total Rounds: 6

My solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BattleofNumbers{
public static void main(String[] args){
    double num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
    double chal1, chal2, chal3, champion;
    double bracket, round = 0;

    System.out.println("Please Enter 5 Numbers: ");
    System.out.println("");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    num1 = in.nextDouble();
    num2 = in.nextDouble();
    num3 = in.nextDouble();
    num4 = in.nextDouble();
    num5 = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("");

    if (num1 > num5){
        chal1 = num1;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 1 Winner: " + chal1);
        }
    else{
        chal1 = num5;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 1 Winner: " + chal1);
    }
    if (num2>num4){
        chal2 = num2;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 2 Winner: " + chal2);
    }else{
        chal2 = num4;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 2 Winner: " + chal2);
    }
    if (chal1>num3){
        chal3 = chal1;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 3 Winner: " + chal3);
    }else{
        chal3 = num3;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 3 Winner: " +chal3);
    }
    if (chal3 > chal2){
        champion = chal3;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 4 Winner: " + champion);
    }else{
        champion = chal2;
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round 4 Winner: " + champion);
    }
    bracket = round / 2;
    System.out.println("=====================");

    System.out.println("The Champion: " + champion);
    System.out.println("No. of Rounds: " + round );
    System.out.println("No. of Brackets: " + bracket);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a specific question ?

Comment: is there any way i could make my code shorter and readable?

Comment: Please have a look at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since you have working code that would be the best place to get help on coding practices.

Comment: Have you learned [`arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) yet?

Comment: Also [`recursion`](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-recursion/) would help.

Comment: @PM77-1 can you give me a sample pls??

Comment: I'll take note of that @PM77-1 thanks..

Comment: @TiGeRMaQ, arrays and recursion are both very large subjects.  You might want to read up on them.  Recusrion especially.  There have been entire books written on the subject.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Thanks..

Comment: can anyone post their own version of solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a small implementation using arrays and I would call it semi-recursion. I'm sure it's not perfect, but it's a more generic approach because the amount of input numbers is dynamic and the condition check programmed only once. Feel free to give feedback on this, maybe someone has an idea to perform each check recursively.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BattleofNumbers {

  double[] nums;
  int amount, round = 0;

  double champ;

  Scanner in;

  public BattleofNumbers() {
      in = new Scanner(System.in);
      initValues();
      processGame();
  }

  public void processGame() {
      champ = calcChamp(nums);
      System.out.println("=====================");
      System.out.println("The Champion: " + champ);
      System.out.println("No. of Rounds: " + round);
      System.out.println("No. of Brackets: "
            + (int) Math.ceil((double) round / 2));
  }

  private void initValues() {
      System.out.println("Please enter amount of numbers:");
      amount = in.nextInt();

      nums = new double[amount];

      for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
          System.out.println("Please enter " + (i + 1) + ". number:");
          nums[i] = in.nextDouble();
      }

      System.out.println("");
  }

  public double calcChamp(double[] nums) {
      double[] nexts = new double[(int)Math.ceil(((double) nums.length / 2))];

      for (int first = 0, second = (nums.length - 1); first <= second; first++, second--) {
          if (nums[first] > nums[second]) {
              nexts[first] = nums[first];
          } else {
              nexts[first] = nums[second];
          }
          round++;
          System.out
                .println("Winner of round " + round + ": " + nexts[first]);
      } 

      if (nexts.length == 1) {
          return nexts[0];
      } else {
          return calcChamp(nexts);
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new BattleofNumbers();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know how experienced you are, but you should use arrays instead of 5 single variables: `double[] nums = new double[5];`. Also, the variable "brackets" isn't needed because it is always round/2 so you can replace it: `System.out.println("No. of Brackets: " + round/2);`
- Because line 2 and line 3 of every if-else-block are used in both the if- and the else-block, you should outsource them (and thereby reduce the amount of code):

  ```
  if (num1 > num5){
   chal1 = num1;
   // round++;
   // System.out.println("Round 1 Winner: " + chal1);
   }
  else {
   chal1 = num5;
   // round++;
   // System.out.println("Round 1 Winner: " + chal1);
   }
  round++;
  System.out.println("Round 1 Winner: " + chal1);
  ```
- "round" seems to be constant at 4. You could stop counting it up and just declare it with 4: `double round = 4;`

Answer (score 0):

This solution shows you how you can use ArrayList for such things (and how it is unlikely to be used in real code):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How many contestants are there? ");
      int size = in.nextInt();
      while(size-- > 0){
        System.out.println("Contestant: ");
        nums.add(in.nextDouble());
      }
      while(nums.size() > 1){
        System.out.println("ROUND STARTED, contestants are: " + nums);
        int i = 0;

        while(i < nums.size()){
          nums.set(i, Math.max(nums.get(i), nums.get(nums.size()-1)));
          if(i != nums.size() - 1)
            nums.remove(nums.size() -1);
          i++;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Competition has ended, the winner is: " + nums.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just realized, that i can get input from XML or database, but i need documentation to get input from command line.

Comment: Oh and yes, my solution does not provide all the output you wanted, but that's what you should figure out how to do.